# What kind of app can be found with FindPackagesForUser method

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to open PowerPoint in my uwp projct,and I use the function FindPackagesForUser. I have added the rescap in the manifest. The code is as follows:

```
var pkgManager = new PackageManager();
var pkg = pkgManager.FindPackagesForUser(String.Empty, Microsoft.Office.Desktop.PowerPoint_8wekyb3d8bbwe).FirstOrDefault();
if (pkg == null) return null;
var apps = await pkg.GetAppListEntriesAsync();
var firstApp = apps.FirstOrDefault();
```

however, the pkg returns null. 'Microsoft.Office.Desktop.PowerPoint_8wekyb3d8bbwe' is the packagename od powerpoint. And if I replace it to 'Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_8wekyb3d8bbwe', the packagename of local calculator, it will success. I really wonder why.

Comment: sometimes pkg is not null but firstApp is null

Answer (score 0):

[`FindPackagesForUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.management.deployment.packagemanager.findpackagesforuser) is used to find packages installed for the specified user. Actually the find path is `C:\Users\YouAccount\AppData\Local\Packages`, you could not find `Microsoft.Office.Desktop.PowerPoint_8wekyb3d8bbwe` [product folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/mobile-devices/product-ids-in-windows-10-mobile) under Packages, because it is desktop product id.

The produce id of uwp powerpoint is [`Microsoft.Office.PowerPoint_8wekyb3d8bbwe`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/powerpoint-mobile/9wzdncrfjb5q?activetab=pivot%3Aoverviewtab), if you have installed it you will find the folder.

Comment: But I can find Microsoft.Office.Desktop.PowerPoint_8wekyb3d8bbwe product folder under Packages

Comment: @曹雨晴, `Microsoft.Office.Desktop.PowerPoint_8wekyb3d8bbwe` is desktop product id, and it does not store in the packages folder.

Comment: but it does in my computer, I don't know how to post a picture

Comment: You mean you have not installed powerpoint into you computer?

Comment: You could post a image link.